# installing git from debian wheezy backports: anyway i see old package version

Tags: debian, git, apt, debian-wheezy, aptitude

I need to install git 1.8.* version.

1. I added backports to my sources.list;
2. Removed current installed git via `apt-get remove git`;
3. Executed `apt-get update` to update my packages list
4. `aptitude show git` still shows `Version: 1:1.7.10.4-1+wheezy1`

What i am doing wrong?

Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main

# deb multimedia
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free

# wheezy backpors
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main
```

P.S. i also tried to execute `apt-get install git --reinstall`, but it has no effect - version is still 1.7

P.P.S. Yes, i am sure it should be 1.8. in backports: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/git

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backport repositories has lower priority than main/updates/security repositories. There are several ways you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install git/wheezy-backports
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install git
```

Modify the apt.conf and add the following line:

```
APT::Default-Release "wheezy-backports";
```

Or in the preferences file:

```
Package: git
Pin: origin release a=wheezy-backports
Pin-Priority: 990
```